# Значение словосочетания во фразе "в соответствии с настоящим руководством"

Tags: фразеология

Иногда приходится встречаться с такой фразой, примерно: "в соответствии с настоящим руководством...". Контекст бывает разный, например "привести в соответствие с настоящим...", либо "только в соответствии"...

Хочется разобраться даже не в происхождении словосочетаний "настоящее руководство"  или "настоящий документ", сколько понять значение... Может быть с контексте "данный документ, который читаете сейчас"? Или "настоящесть" его юридическая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Настоящее" указывает строго на источник, который в данный момент читают. 
"Данный" или "этот" менее ознозначно: такие слова могут использоваться и для ссылки на другой, уже упомянутый источник ("данный" больше подходит для подробной ссылки).
О юридической значимости документа, на который ссылаются, может говорить слово "действующий" (официальный документ, закон). Но в содержании документа возможно и такое: "настоящий документ является юридическим основанием для того-то".

Comment: Спасибо, убеждение подтверждено: рядом с "настоящий..." буду впредь вспоминать "действующий...".

Answer (score 1):

Одно из значений слова "настоящий" – этот, данный (в словарях дано с пометой *книжн*.)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что проще всего объяснить это ***настоящий*** особенностями юридического и/или делового стиля разного рода документов. Насколько понимаю, упомянутый в вопросе пример  использования в преамбуле или заключении - единственный (с небольшими вариантами) случай использования "настоящий" в данном значении: "настоящий документ устанавливает" "настоящий документ вводится в действие (с такой-то даты, таким-то способом)", "настоящим документом регулируется то-то и то-то", "настоящий документ содержит" - и т.д. Где эта фраза написана, тот документ и ***настоящий***. Других примеров я что-то не вспоминаю, видимо их и нет. Антоним (смысловой) - "все остальные".

"Настоящий" - тот, в котором написана эта фраза, тот, где это "настоящий" напечатано.
В этом смысле он актуальный. Но не более. 
"Действующий" - как и было сказано, несет несколько другой смысл.

Comment: "Настоящий" - тот, в котором написана эта фраза, тот, где это "настоящий" напечатано.

Согласен, ещё может подразумеваться "именно эта версия" документа

Comment: >ещё может подразумеваться "именно эта версия" документа  
  
Вот тут я бы поостерегся. Если "настоящий документ", то разговоры о "версии" тут уже не к месту. А если написано "настоящая версия" то это уже не "подразумевается", а *написано явно*. 
Смысл, впрочем, тот же: настоящая версия - та версия, в которой  где эта фраза написана. 
есть еще вариант типа "настоящая версия программы" - но это тоже применительно к той версии, к которой прилагается документация.

Answer (score 0):

"Настоящее" указывает строго на источник, который в данный момент читают. 
"Данный" или "этот" менее ознозначно: такие слова могут использоваться и для ссылки на другой, уже упомянутый источник ("данный" больше подходит для подробной ссылки).
О юридической значимости документа, на который ссылаются, может говорить слово "действующий" (официальный документ, закон). Но в содержании документа возможно и такое: "настоящий документ является юридическим основанием для того-то".